# How to check the Software version invoked by cmake

Tags: build, cmake, cmake-gui

I am invoking a software from CMAKE to generate required files for build.Is it possible to print the version of software invoked in the build window..?

Comment: Which part of the problem is difficult for you: **extracting version** of the "software" or **printing something** during the *build process*?

Comment: @Tsyvarev i could not extract the version of the software ...

Comment: Extracting version of the software **fully depends on the software itself**. See documentation on it and how it can be invoked. Usually `<executable> -v` or `<executable> --version` prints version and some related things.

Comment: @Santz What software?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks!

Comment: @arrowd beyond comapre and some other sofwares

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, the exact way to output the version will depend on the executable itself.
Lets assume it is `<executable> --version`.

Then it CMake it will look like:

```
find_program(EXECUTABLE_RUNTIME <executable>)
if ("${EXECUTABLE_RUNTIME}" STREQUAL "EXECUTABLE_RUNTIME-NOTFOUND")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "<executable> runtime could not be found!")
else()
  execute_process(COMMAND "${EXECUTABLE_RUNTIME}" --version
                  OUTPUT_VARIABLE EXECUTABLE_VERSION
                  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
  message(STATUS "Found <executable> runtime at ${EXECUTABLE_VERSION}, version ${EXECUTABLE_VERSION}")
endif()
```

A possible footgun is to include the command arguments in the quotes (e.g. `"${EXECUTABLE_RUNTIME} --version"`, if you do this the output variable will be empty.
`OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE` will remove the new line which is very often present after the version.